# FFMPEG - Concat more than 2 streams - No output pad can be associated to link label

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

I'm running the following FFMPEG Command:

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -y -filter_complex 
[0:v]trim=0,crop=1468.8000000000002:864:225.59999999999994:108,scale=1080:1080,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[track1];/
[track1]split[track2][track3][track4]; /
[track2]trim=1:4,setpts=1*(PTS-STARTPTS)[track5]; /
[track3]trim=4:6,setpts=1*(PTS-STARTPTS)[track6]; /
[track4]trim=6:7,setpts=1*(PTS-STARTPTS)[track7]; /
[track5][track6][track7]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[track11] -map [track11] -shortest -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -coder 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -g 30 -bf 2 output.mp4
```

and it returns the error:

> [AVFilterGraph @ 000001fc3fe38380] No output pad can be associated to link label 'track3'.
> Error initializing complex filters.
> Invalid argument

If I remove the "track4" copy of the stream and its corresponding trim command, it runs ok. Working:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -y -filter_complex [0:v]trim=0,crop=1468.8000000000002:864:225.59999999999994:108,scale=1080:1080,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[track1]; /
[track1]split[track2][track3]; /
[track2]trim=1:4,setpts=1*(PTS-STARTPTS)[track5]; /
[track3]trim=4:6,setpts=1*(PTS-STARTPTS)[track6]; /
[track5][track6]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[track11] -map [track11] -shortest -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -coder 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -g 30 -bf 2 output.mp4
```

I don't understand why adding an additional copy of the stream would cause it to fail. Any suggestions?

**I'm on windows and running it as a 1 line command. I added the "/" and line breaks to make it more readable.**

Comment: Maybe split=3 helps: `[track1]split=3[track2][track3][track4];`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов That worked. Thanks! If you submit it as an answer, I'll make it as correct.